# Why do my buttons keep becoming numbers?

Tags: templates, upgrade

After updates our Civi installation (which is within WordPress in case it matters) often switched all buttons to numbers instead of their labels.

I presume this might have something to do with translation or templating? It tends to go away when I do all the usual post-upgrade things like clearing caches etc, but no amount of fiddling is fixing them this time.

Can anyone suggest what could be related? What can I try? What might cause this?

It's happening to all Civi buttons on the frontend and the backend, but not any non-Civi buttons.

[image: On the front end (CiviContribute donation page)]

[image: On the backend: (In the settings page)]

Comment: Could you post a link? That might make this easier to figure out.
Do you have anything set in Administration - Customize Data and Screens - Word Replacements?

Comment: Sure! Here's a front-end link:
https://www.forwarduk.org.uk/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=2&fixed_amount=1

The only Word Replacement in there is "State/Provine" to "County".

Comment: If you temporarily switch the theme to a stock theme does it still happen?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with Civi and can't find out how change at Civi theme to see if that fixes anything on the backend.

Switching the WordPress frontend to TwentyTwenty doesn't resolve the front end issue.

Comment: Very interesting, I've never seen this.  What version of Civi is this?  I don't have any buttons next to my Access Keys, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like there.

Comment: Ah those are the two buttons which are supposed to say (something like) "Reset Paths" and "Clear Caches"  - they're on the "Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths" page.

I was running 5.35.0 but am now on 5.35.1.

Comment: Someone else had a similar problem in chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/metit8hchjb95rfunbsszi866c. It sounded like it was related to the haystack theme?

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from 5.28 last night and ran into this same problem. I had an old version of haystack theme installed which was causing the problem (disabling the theme would bring the labels back).

You'll want to disable and uninstall haystack, delete the directory from your wp/uploads/civicrm/ext/ directory and then install the updated theme from here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/haystacktheme

That fixed it for me.